# Sql Server Trigger and PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger in al Sql Server

```
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @exe nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @exe2 nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @idEmpl nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @fecha nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @entSal nvarchar(255);

SELECT @idEmpl = Id_de_People, @fecha = CONVERT(varchar,cast(60*60*24*(cast(Fecha as float)-25567) as int)-3600-7200), @entSal = EntSal FROM inserted;

SET @exe = 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php.exe -f "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\marcaje_to_attendance.php" idEmpl=' + @idEmpl +' fecha='+ @fecha +' entSal='+ @entSal +'';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @exe;

SET @exe2 = '"C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\attendance_bulk_2.php idEmpl=' + @idEmpl +' fecha='+ @fecha +' entSal='+ @entSal +'';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @exe2;

INSERT INTO log_trigger (log_fecha, log_id_empleado, momento_entrada, ent_o_sal) VALUES (@fecha, @idEmpl, GETDATE(), @entSal) ;
```

This code makes a call for any insert (the data base recived a few insert by second) to a php file who recive thats values to connect with other system.

My problem is that my php don't recive any call because I writte a log for any call of them.

I don't know how can I see a SQL Server log of the trigger or if I have any error in the trigger code.

I put an insert to other table for knows if the triggert works and it's ok because I see the insert of each row.

Can you help me?.

Thanks

Comment: The only problem I see with your trigger code is that if it ever is triggered by a multi-row insert, it will only handle one of the rows.   Is nothing getting written in your `log_trigger` table?   If the trigger raised an error, the insert that triggered it should get rolled back, so you wouldn't get an insert into the table that the trigger is on.   Is that happening?

Comment: And how can handle a multi-row insert?. Thanks for your answer. When I recive a bulk or multi-row insert, the insert that I put in the log_trigger have the all records. But in my php file, I don't recive anything. I can't see any call to my php

Comment: Usually, you can handle multi-row inserts by joining to the `inserted` table instead of selecting from it to populate variables.   Though in your case, to do the xp_cmdshell calls once for each row in `inserted` you would need to use a cursor.

Comment: I would suggest not doing all this logic in your trigger in the first place. Instead use your trigger to insert values to a staging table. Then create a sql job to do the rest of the work here and schedule it as regularly as you need it. You don't want to make your trigger wait on webpages to load.

Comment: Thank you Sean for your answerd. The insert is only to verified if the trigger works because when I try to view the log record in php I don't see anything because I think that the php call maybe it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You say the insert to `log_trigger` is working, but the calls to php.exe seem to not be happening.

In that case, the problem is either internal to your php files, or maybe a result of the php.exe not being present where you are specifying.  You have php.exe installed in that location on your SQL Server?

Comment: Hi, yes, the php.exe is in that location and sql have the permission to access. Equal to the php file. The location is correct and the permission it is granted